What does the term "feet" mean in plants?
In my recent post, there was this quote as part of the answer:

And also, Succulents and Christmas cactus like drier feet, ferns and spider plants like wetter feet.
*Bold added for emphasis

In reference to the term "feet" what does this specifically refer to and is this a term ubiquitous to gardening/plants?

It refers to the soil, and the roots.
For example, likes drier feet means that the plant thrives in drier soil.

yeah, like when we say we have wet feet, we mean the outer skin and the environment outside (socks, shoes, etc.) not our foot which should be full of blood.)

I was using 'foot' to mean "something resembling a foot in position or use".  I don't think it's a specific botanical term.  Roots are just analogous to feet, to me.
But I am not alone. Mohit Kumar Roa thinks so too, here's a sculpture of his.

